# Why python is low level?

Tags: python, c, assembly, low-level

I have one confusion as python generate

`source code ->> byte code --> python virtual machine`

does c language also generate byte code or it compile directly ?

If c doesn't generate byte code that's why it's consider as Low level language? Because Assembly also doesn't generate byte code that's why it's low level because its directly execute on machine?

Comment: It depends on your point of view.

Comment: If a language is compiled to machine code directly or not have little to no bearing on if a language is low-.level or not. Even an interpreted language could be low-level.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Byte codes are not natural to the CPU so they need interpretation (by a CPU native code called interpreter).

[image]

The python code you write is compiled into python bytecode, which creates file with extension .pyc. If compiles,your bytecode, present in pyc file, created in compilation step, is then executed by appropriate virtual machines.

**Is there any python compiler?**

PyPy it is JIT compiler for python code. Nuitka, Nuitka attempts to translate pure Python not into bytecode, but into machine code (via C++ compiler), while using libpython at run time. Another one is ShedSkin. It compiles implicitly statically typed Python to C++, stand-alone programs or extension modules.